# ORA 12154 - unable to connect from toad/SQLplus

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

when i try to connect any DataBase in my TNSNAMES.ora file SQLPLUS throws

```
ORA-12154: TNS could not resolve service name
```

I've already checked this stuff:

```
TNS_ADMIN environment variable is defined as "C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\NETWORK\ADMIN"  

"C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora" was located  

The following connect descriptor was found for my_db in the tnsnames.ora file  

my_db=  
  (DESCRIPTION=  
    (ADDRESS=  
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)  
      (HOST=local.db)  
      (PORT=1521)  
    )  
    (CONNECT_DATA=  
      (SID=SCMPROD)  
    )  
  )  

"C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\NETWORK\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora" was located  

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH specifies TNSNAMES in the sqlnet.ora file
```

the question is:

what is missing?

## UPDATE

Now on SqlPlus using `the usr/pwd@SELFTEST` connection string it works

In can't be an error on the server because on my old PC it still accept my connection an all my company works on it.

The tnsname.ora

```
SELFTEST=
  (DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=10.100.2.7)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVER=dedicated)
      (SERVICE_NAME=GOLDtest)
    )
  )
```

The problem still exist trying to connect from Toad for Oracle...

Comment: How exactly are you trying to connect? The error doesn't match the file - the TNS entry you showed has a SID, while the error refers to the service name. So what is your connection string, and what is the matching entry in `tnsnames.ora`? Is the database you're trying to connect to actually up, and do you have the correct service name specified? What does `lsnrctl status` on that server show?

Comment: @AlexPoole it reponse `TNS-01101: Could not find service name 10.100.2.7.1521` for this server. But on another one, with the same problem, it give me `TNS-01189: The listener could not authenticate the user`

Comment: Check the content of `listener.ora` on that server, it looks like you have a mistake in that. (the `.1521` looks odd, but so does getting a dotted value as a service name). You're only giving us partial information so it's hard to guess exactly what is wrong with your configuration.

Comment: the `10.100.2.7.1521` is only a paste error...sorry    Tell me all the info you want.

Comment: The connection string you're using in SQL\*Plus; the `tnsnames.ora` entry you think that's actually referring to (or the whole file on your client machine); the `listerner.ora` file from the server. All added as edits to the question, not as comments, as they'd be unreadable. (And if you can connect to the database locally on the server, then `service_names` and `local_listener` init parameters wouldn't hurt).

Comment: IDK where to find service_names and local_listener  init parameters... if you are telling about enviroment variables i've haven't set those

Comment: How are you connecting from Toad - what are your connection settings? I'd *guess* you're giving the service name as `selftest`instead of `goldtest`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ORA-12154: TNS could not resolve service name
>
> ```
> my_db=  
>   (DESCRIPTION=  
>     (ADDRESS=  
>       (PROTOCOL=TCP)  
>       (HOST=local.db)  
>       (PORT=1521)  
>     )  
>     (CONNECT_DATA=  
>       (SID=SCMPROD)  
>     )  
>   )
> ```

The error is about incorrect **service name**. I see your **tnsnames.ora** doesn't have the service_name, rather you have mentioned **SID**. Probably this is the cause of the error.

You could edit the tnsnames.ora as:

```
SCMPROD =
 (DESCRIPTION = 
   (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
   )
 (CONNECT_DATA =
   (SERVICE_NAME = SCMPROD)
 )
)
```

Assuming, `SCMPROD` is the **service_name**.

Comment: The error would refer to SID if it was using that TNS alias though? I don't think we're seeing the relevant TNS entries yet. (Although I also feel like I need coffee...)

Comment: @AlexPoole What I am contemplating is that OP is not showing us the entire picture and telling us his version of problem understanding. With tns errors, it is usually a silly problem in the end. It is all about describing the problem properly. :-)

Comment: Yep, agree completely. My comments on the question are trying to tease more out. Currently looks like a `listener.ora` problem, but hard to tell still.

Answer (score 0):

From the [source](http://ora-12154.ora-code.com)

> **ORA-12154**:    TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
>   **Cause**:    A connection to a database or other service was requested using a connect identifier, and the connect identifier specified could
>   not be resolved into a connect descriptor using one of the naming
>   methods configured. For example, if the type of connect identifier
>   used was a net service name then the net service name could not be
>   found in a naming method repository, or the repository could not be
>   located or reached.
>   **Action**:
>
> - If you are using local naming (TNSNAMES.ORA file):
> - Make sure that "TNSNAMES" is listed as one of the values of the NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile (SQLNET.ORA)
> - Verify that a TNSNAMES.ORA file exists and is in the proper directory and is accessible.
> - Check that the net service name used as the connect identifier exists in the TNSNAMES.ORA file.
> - Make sure there are no syntax errors anywhere in the TNSNAMES.ORA file. Look for unmatched parentheses or stray characters. Errors in a
>     TNSNAMES.ORA file may make it unusable.
> - If you are using directory naming:
> - Verify that "LDAP" is listed as one of the values of the NAMES.DIRETORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile (SQLNET.ORA).
> - Verify that the LDAP directory server is up and that it is accessible.
> - Verify that the net service name or database name used as the connect identifier is configured in the directory.
> - Verify that the default context being used is correct by specifying a fully qualified net service name or a full LDAP DN as the connect
>     identifier
> - If you are using easy connect naming:
> - Verify that "EZCONNECT" is listed as one of the values of the NAMES.DIRETORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile (SQLNET.ORA).
> - Make sure the host, port and service name specified are correct.
> - Try enclosing the connect identifier in quote marks. See the Oracle Net Services Administrators Guide or the Oracle operating system
>     specific guide for more information on naming.

Comment: Yes, the error is `ORA-12154: TNS could not resolve service name`